# Datagridview how to cast selected row to custom object

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I use c# winforms with MSSQL database.
I have table in database "Pilots"
, i fill datagridview "dgvPilots", with data from Pilots table.

```
dgvPilots.DataSource = Connection.dm.Pilots.ToList();
```

I enable multiselect.
now i need to get multiselected data from datagridview.
How can i multiselected rows cast to "Pilots" object and get PilotsID.

My current error is "Unable to cast object type DataGridViewRow to type ".Data.Pilots"...

i also try casting like this

```
dgvPilots.SelectedRows.Cast<Pilots>().ToList();
```

but it return DataGridViewRow item type.

Comment: post the code for the datagridview please

Comment: did you try the DataBoundItem property of the DataGridViewRow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will need to iterate the collection and go after the DataBoundItem property which is the underlying data.

```
var pilots = new List<Pilots>(grid.SelectedRows.Count);

for(int index = 0; index < grid.SelectedRows.Count; index++)
{
   var selectedRow = grid.SelectedRows[index];
   var pilot = (Pilots)selectedRow.DataBoundItem;

   pilots.Add(pilot);
}
```

The code above shows how you can achieve this, (I freehanded the code so forgive any syntax errors).

Here is the msdn article on the DataBoundItem property: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what your DB structure is but

```
var selectedPilots = dgvPilots.SelectedRows.Cast<Pilots>().ToList();
```

is the proper way to do it. However I do suspect `Pilots` in your case is a `DataTable`, and what you need is to cast those items to proper `Class` type -  If I'd have to shoot, I'd say you've got a `Pilot` (singular) class, that you should cast to.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int> indexes = DataGrid1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Index).ToList();

            foreach (i in indexes)
            {
                Pilots Pilot = (Pilots)DataGrid1.Rows[i].DataBoundItem;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple generic extension method is what I've always used:

```
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
            list.Add((T)rows[i].DataBoundItem);
        return list;
    }
```

Use: `dgvPilots.SelectedRows.ToList<Pilots>()`

Answer (score 3):

First, wait three years for your answer.

Second, please, don't iterate.

```
var selectedPilots = 
            (from DataGridViewRow cada in dgvPilots.SelectedRows select cada.DataBoundItem)
            .Select(x => (Pilots)x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it without explicitly iterating over the SelectedRows

`dgvPilots.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(row => row.DataBoundItem as Pilots);`

or

`dgvPilots.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(row => (Pilots) row.DataBoundItem);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I found out this:

```
IList<Pilots> pilots = (BindingList<Pilots>)((BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource).List;
```