# Casting a DataRow in DataGridView to a custom object?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to cast a DataRow to custom object, when I double click a row, so this it what sounds to me the right way doing it:

```
DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)gv_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
//this to see the data, but the table contains all the rows in the grid
var table = selectedRow.DataView.ToTable();
```

the data in the grid is a view from SQL, I generated a class holding the same data the view returns, so I want when I double click the `DataGridView` the selected row is casted to the type I created

Comment: Can you cast as per this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520195/datagridview-how-to-cast-selected-row-to-custom-object#23520452

Comment: When I used `grid.SelectedRows[index]` it throws exception , index out ofrange

Comment: Are you using a BindingSource by any chance? There would be no need to ask the grid for its selected row.

Comment: No, I don't using a BindingSource

Comment: You might consider using a BindingSource especially based on one of your comments. The current property of the BindingSource will be the object. The effort to learn and use data binding is well worth it.

Comment: Instead of DataSource?

Comment: You assign the DataSource to the BindingSource. [Here's the first resource I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)  (I would ignore the SQL part since you already have that solved and I hate use of SqlCommandBuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I generated a class holding the same data the view returns, so I want
>   when I double click the DataGridView the selected row is casted to the
>   type I created

Use collection of this classes as DataSource for DataGridView

```
List<MyClass> allData = GetDataFromDatabase();
gv_Search.DataSource = allData;
```

Then on row click you can access selected instance of `MyClass`

```
var selected = (MyClass)gv_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;

Console.WriteLine($"Selected Id = {selected.Id}"); // Use selected data
```

Inside `GetDataFromDatabase` you will read data from database straight to the instances of `MyClass`

```
var allItems = new List<MyClass>();
using (var connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = New SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new MyClass
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                Name = reader.GetString(1),
                Birthdate = reader.GetDatetime(2)
            };

            allItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

return allItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but if you want to cast some custom object to another one, you can use ***Conversion operator***:

```
public static explicit operator DataRowView(VwCustomerSizes arg)
{
    DataRowView drv = new DataRowView();
    drv.Prop1 = (Prop1Type)arg.Prop1; //of course if they need casting
    drv.Prop2 = (Prop2Type)arg.Prop2;
    drv.Prop3 = (Prop3Type)arg.Prop3;
    . . .
    drv.PropN = (PropNType)arg.PropN;
    return drv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataRowView` has a `Row` property that should be the `VwCustomerSizes` that you're after.