# How to cast data to nested class in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq to cast data row to MapValueFields class, but row values are strings, so it trigger casting error, any help is appreciated.

**Inside class**

```
 public partial class MapValueFields
  {
    public GrandTotal Amount { get; set; }
    ...
  }

 public partial class GrandTotal
  {
    public string DoubleValue { get; set; }
  }
```

**I tried this**

```
 List<MapValueFields> items = viewLaundry.ToTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(t => new MapValueFields()
 {
   Amount = t.Field<GrandTotal>("Total Amount"), // here is the problem
   ...
 }).ToList();
```

casting error say string not cast to the GrandTotal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting a DataRow in DataGridView to a custom object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565296/casting-a-datarow-in-datagridview-to-a-custom-object)

Comment: It is not related, first has diff exception, second it not related to nested class third my problem is on ```t.Field<GrandTotal>``` I hope it clear

Comment: Is the object in your DataRow's [Total Amount] column really an object of type GrandTotal? Seems like it's a `string` to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case for other users

```
Amount = new GrandTotal() { DoubleValue = t.Field<string>("Total Amount") },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the value in the column is a string. Just because a GrandTotal *has a* string does not mean it *is a* string. Cast can only perform is-a conversions. You'll have to make a new object and assign the string to the relevant property

```
List<MapValueFields> items = viewLaundry.ToTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(t => new MapValueFields()
 {
   Amount = new GrandTotal { DoubleValue = t.Field<string>("Total Amount") 
   ...
 }).ToList();
```

You could also use `(string)t["Total Amount"]` for a more compact syntax